# file transfer in xmpp using strophe

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I know this type of question is posted earlier also.
But I didn't got any answer on that link.

I am using open fire server, XMPP, and strophe for html chat client.
now I want to transfer image to all subscriber of my pub-sub node.

Is it possible to implement file transfer using strophe?

Answer (score 1):

a way maybe is upload the file to yoyur server and sen the link to the another user like a message....later the user clicks the link and download it or show the source as an image in the chat area...